# How to get CPU Percentage as a Counter?

Tags: linux, monitoring, cpu

I would like to  monitor total CPU utilization percentage as a counter. The reason I would like it as a counter is that data won't be lost between samples (and I can have the graphing side calculate the rate).

My initial approach was to use `/proc/uptime` with the formula `(uptime-(idle_time/num_core))*100`. This generally seems to be accurate across a large number of servers (something like 98% of the time), but sometimes I seem to get erroneous results. For example the following seems to suggest that there was negative CPU usage, which doesn't really make sense:

```
[root@ny-lb05 ~]# echo -e "scale=10\n ($(cut -f1 -d' ' /proc/uptime)-($(cut -f2 -d' ' /proc/uptime)/16))*100" | bc
5646895.3750000000
[root@ny-lb05 ~]# echo -e "scale=10\n ($(cut -f1 -d' ' /proc/uptime)-($(cut -f2 -d' ' /proc/uptime)/16))*100" | bc
5646891.5625000000
```

On this server I'm running:

`Linux ny-lb05.ds.stackexchange.com 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 19:59:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Does someone see an error in this method of calculation? Is there a better way to get CPU utilization as a counter?

**Update:**
So what I'm after is the total utilization time as a monotonically increasing counter. I would expect that total utilization should never *decrease*. But that seems to be the case with the following:

`[root@ny-lb05 ~]# read uptime idle </proc/uptime; echo -e "scale=1000\n ($uptime*16-($idle))" | bc
903874.23
[root@ny-lb05 ~]# read uptime idle </proc/uptime; echo -e "scale=1000\n ($uptime*16-($idle))" | bc
903870.29`

Also, according to /proc/cpuinfo, cores=siblings so I believe HT is not enabled.

**Update 2:**
TLDR; /proc/uptime is bugged, use /proc/stat instead.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks': According to your answer `uptime * num_core - idle_time = total active processor seconds`. Doesn't it logically follow that total active processor seconds should never *decrease*?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry.  There can't have been more idle time than total time since the last sample (comment deleted).

Comment: BTW, it terms of calculating a current usage % ala `top`, I've done this in the past using fields from `/proc/stat`; the first `cpu` is a combined total, which is useful (then you have breakdowns for each individual core).  You then need two samples to determine usage in relation to a unit of time.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks': Good idea, I'll do the math from /proc/stat and see if I run into this same bug on the machine exhibiting the behavior.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks': Do you what subset of the /proc/stat columns summed equals utilization? Is it user/system/nice?

Comment: I've added some details about this to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (uptime-(idle_time/num_core))

May give an idea of how long the system has been busy, in seconds. Multipling that by 100 makes it centiseconds -- is that your intention?

IMO it would make more sense to consider how many processor seconds in total were available, and subtract the idle time from that:

```
uptime * num_core - idle_time = total active processor seconds
```

A utilization metric might be:

```
active seconds / (uptime * num_core)
```

E.g., if the system has been up for 10 seconds on 4 cores with 5 seconds of idle_time:

```
(10 * 4 - 5) / (10 * 4) = 0.875
```

87.5% utilization.

Or:

```
(10 - 5 / 4) / 10 = 0.875
```

Same thing, saves an operation.

---

> Is there a better way to get CPU utilization as a counter?

I've done this in a system diagnostics C++ library by parsing the first line of `/proc/stat`, which is a combined total for all cores.  The first three fields are user time, low priority (aka nice) time, and system time.  The total of these is the amount of active time (note the unit here is not seconds, see `/proc/stat` under `man proc`).

If you poll this over 5 seconds, assuming a USER_HZ of 100, where `total_a` is
the first sample (user + nice + sys) and `total_b` is the second sample:

```
(total_b - total_a) / 5 / 100 / num_cores = usage ratio
```

If you multiply that by 100, you have a percentage indicating an average over the 5 second interval.

Here's the logic:

- `total_b - total_a` = active time between samples
- Divided by the duration of the sample, 5 seconds.
- Divided by the units per second of the measurement (USER_HZ)
- Divided by the number of cores

USER_HZ is almost certainly 100.  To check:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    printf (
        "%ld\n", 
        sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Compile: `gcc whatever.c`, run `./a.out`.

It will be hard to get an accurate duration for this with shell tools, so you could either keep an increasing measure of the total active time (I think that is your intention) or use a fairly long interval, e.g. 30+ seconds.

Comment: This seems to work. I'm using opentsdb, which does a rate calculation for me from counters, so all I need to do is send it user+nice+system from the first line of /proc/stat divided by the number of cores. Whatever bug is messing with /proc/uptime doesn't seem to impact /proc/stat.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is probably because you are reading `/proc/cputime` from two separate processes. The idle time will will increase slightly between each `cat`, giving the possibility for a lower reading the second time. I recommend doing this instead:

```
read uptime idle </proc/cputime
echo -e "scale=10\n ($uptime-($idle/16))*100" | bc
```

Also, if you want your results to be a total utilisation percentage, then you should divide by the uptime again:

```
read uptime idle </proc/cputime
echo -e "scale=10\n ($uptime-($idle/16))/$uptime*100" | bc
```

Comment: Nope, it my actual code it is a single read: `[kbrandt@ny-lb06: ~] read uptime idle </proc/uptime; echo -e "scale=10\n ($uptime-($idle/16))*100" | bc                                          <990@8:03>
6259851.5000000000
[kbrandt@ny-lb06: ~] read uptime idle </proc/uptime; echo -e "scale=10\n ($uptime-($idle/16))*100" | bc                                          <991@8:03>
6259842.8125000000`

Comment: Also, the difference here would be pretty insignificant except in extremely unusual cases.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks', the difference is only 50ms, which is about right for the overhead of `cut`, especially is most of the processors on the system are idle.

Comment: That's why I'm saying it's insignificant, unless the system has only been up for a few hundred milliseconds.  It is more efficient to do it in one sample, but the OP's problem here is mostly his metric (I notice we've both come to the same conclusion on that).

Comment: The metric I'm going for is a monotonically increasing counter of utilization, so on the query side I can take the deltas, divide by total seconds, and get a rate.

Comment: **Why don't you just spell out in exact terms what you want,** as per my example? Do that *first*, then implement it.  Do not do both things at the same time, that is just poor process.  What you have now calculates an abstraction of busy time in centiseconds, which makes very little sense.

Comment: @KyleBrandt, ok then you probably shouldn't multiply by 100 since the result is not a percentage, but rather in seconds (though I can see the logic for multiplying by 1000 since milliseconds are a common unit). Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is that the number of cores is out. Eg if the system uses hyperthreading maybe it is counting idle time per logical core rather than per actual core.

Comment: @KyleBrandt, what is the output of `nproc`? If it is not this, then surely there must be an inaccuracy in the kernel's reporting somewhere along the line.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks': Updated my question

Comment: @Graeme: nproc outputs 16. My guess is some sort of bug as well, which is why I was wondering if there is a more reliable source

Comment: @TAFKA 'goldilocks': Also, "calculates an abstraction of busy time in centiseconds" is a good way of putting it. I sample that and get that number, sample it again later and get what should be a higher number, then take (sample2_value-sample1_value)/(sample2_time-sample1_time) to get a per second rate of utilization. Having it centiseconds makes it a "percentage"

Comment: @KyleBrandt, no, measuring something in centisecs does not make it a percentage.  Calculating the ratio of that measurement to a theoretical maximum does.

Comment: @psusi: In a per second rate, that maximum number of centi seconds in a second is 100. So it basically "works out". But this is kind of tangential. My problem seems to be that "total busy time" goes down over time as per my update.

Comment: @KyleBrandt, no, it does not "work out", which is why you are getting all sorts of goofy numbers.  You have to have a divide by uptime in there, like goldilocks's answer shows.

Comment: @psusi: If you divide by uptime it is no longer a counter, what I want is a counter.

Comment: @KyleBrandt, either you want the percentage of utilization, in which case, you have to divide by uptime, or you want a count of non idle time, which is not a percentage.

Comment: @psusi: When I take two samples, and turn that into a per/second rate, I end up with centiseconds utlized per second. So for example, I would get 75 centiseconds per second. A second has 100 centiseconds. 75/100*100=75. Hence it the number is the same, regardless of what you want to call it.

Comment: @KyleBrandt There seems to be a real confusion between measurements here, I suggest some background reading on what a percentage actually is. As for you main issue, I have to admit I'm stumped. You can use the `sysinfo` call to get the uptime, but `/proc/uptime` seems the only way for idle time. If you want to see what the kernel actually does for `/proc/uptime` see [fs/proc/uptime.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/uptime.c).